# What does NSURLConnection's error code "-1009" mean?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

When I send a request and get an error with the error code `-1009`, what does that mean? I'm not sure how to handle it.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
      NSLog(@"connection didFailWithError");

   if(error.code==-1009){       
      //do something           
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Since the error returned should be within the `NSURLErrorDomain`, the [code `-1009`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1508628-url_loading_system_error_codes/nsurlerrornotconnectedtointernet) means:

> `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`
>
> Returned when a network resource was requested, but an internet connection is not established and cannot be established automatically, either through a lack of connectivity, or by the user's choice not to make a network connection automatically.

Answer (score 22):

With **Swift**, you can use the [`NSURLError`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/3a75394c670bb7143397327ac7bf5b5fe8d50588/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/NSError.swift#L642) enum for NSURL error domain check:

```
switch NSURLError(rawValue: error.code) {
case .Some(.NotConnectedToInternet):
    print("NotConnectedToInternet")
default: break
}
```

**Swift 3:**

```
switch URLError.Code(rawValue: error.code) {
case .some(.notConnectedToInternet):
    print("NotConnectedToInternet")
default: break
}
```

**Swift 4:**

```
switch URLError.Code(rawValue: error.code) {
case .notConnectedToInternet:
    print("NotConnectedToInternet")
default: break
}
```

Comment: I used this But in the first line the app won't allow me to run I am using swift 4

Comment: the swift show me this massage when I use this code 
Expected declaration
should I use it in view did load or not?

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi sorry, I didn't get it. What message?

Comment: the app won't let me to run because of this Error : Expected declaration

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi I think you have the code in the wrong place. Make sure the code is inside the body of any function. It can not be outside.

Comment: Yes thank you but when this code inside the body wants to run I will get fatal Error because the error in the first line is nil how can I avoid that?

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Please open a question and provide some code to look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

It's `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet` which means, well, that you're not connected to the internet... :)

You can find the error codes in `NSURLError.h`.